# How to get the item id in an onItemClick handler

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, simpleadapter

I have a category table with two columns `category_id` and `name`. I have created a data helper class named `CategoryDataHelper`. I have a method named `getCategoryCursor()` of that helper class which fetches the id and the name from the category table and returns the cursor. Using that cursor, I have used `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display the list of categories. It is working fine.

```
public class Categories extends ListActivity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        categoryDataHelper = new CategoryDataHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor categoryCursor  = categoryDataHelper.getCategoryCursor();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (
                this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                categoryCursor,                                              
                new String[] { CategoryDataHelper.NAME },           
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});  

        // Bind to our new adapter.
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Here I want the category_id  
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Now I want to implement an `OnItemClickListener` and send an Intent with the `category_id` of the selected category. How can I get the id in the `onItemClick()` method?

Comment: isn't id parameter of type long helping you??

Comment: For getting contents of item selected, use
Object o=lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

The object o can be further used to get items.

Comment: What does setListAdapter do and why does it come before list = getListView()?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably should get the cursor from the adapter. This way if your cursor gets replaced you are still are still getting a valid cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) adapterView).getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
long categoryId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CategoryDataHelper.ID));
```

or use `"category_id"` or whatever the name of your column is in place of `CategoryDataHelper.ID`.

Comment: `adapterView` is usually not an adapter. It's a view that uses adapter and therefore have method `getAdapter()`. So, in your example you should call `adapterView.getAdapter()` instead.

Comment: Is it applicable with `SimpleAdapter`?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Zack, I could solve with your post...Excelent!!!
...
I send a parameter from an activity to another so:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Clientes.this, Edc.class);
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
myIntent.putExtra("CLIENTE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In the other activity (EDC)....i get the parameter so:

```
int _clienteId = getIntent().getIntExtra("CLIENTE_ID", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about in onItemclick:

```
categoryCursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

and then from the returned cursor get the ID from your helper?

Answer (score 1):

With the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, the `onItemClick` function passes in the databases id for the selected item. So, the solution is simply

```
long category_id = id
```