# how do i make a list clickable when populating with a cursor object?

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

I'm working on an android app to list the bookmarks stored in the browser and populated onto a list using a cursor, and cursor adapter. I've had no problem populating the list at all, my problem is all in the click. I'm using an onItemClickListener and when the user clicks a list item the app crashes.

The logcat out puts this:

```
10-27 23:54:22.718: ERROR/CursorWindow(315): Bad request for field slot 0,2131034113.    
numRows = 15, numColumns = 12

10-27 23:54:22.738: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(315): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get    
field slot from row 0 col 2131034113 failed
```

below is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;



@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class BookmarksActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Uri bookmarks = Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI;
     final Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(bookmarks, null, null, null, null );
   // Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(bookmarks, bookmark, null, null,
BookmarkColumns.TITLE  );

    String[] bookmark = new String[]{
        BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
        BookmarkColumns.URL,
        BookmarkColumns._ID,
        };


    // Bind to our new adapter.


    int[] views = new int[] {R.id.urlTitle, R.id.urlUrl};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main,
managedCursor, bookmark, views);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

    //list = (listView)adapter;

   this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(managedCursor.getString(R.id.urlUrl)));
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

    getColumnData(managedCursor);


}



//getColumnData will go through the supplied cursor and get the data we need
// in this case webpage titles and urls.
// i will late implement the favicon.
 private void getColumnData(Cursor cur)
 {
    if (cur.moveToFirst()){

        String title;
        String url;

        int titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
        int urlColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL);

        String imagePath;

        do{
            title = cur.getString(titleColumn);
            url = cur.getString(urlColumn);

            Log.d("+-CURSOR-+", title + " " + url);

        }while(cur.moveToNext());

    }




 }
}
```

Comment: The answer on the following link looks good. Note that you're not even using "position" in your onItemClick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553176/android-simplecursoradapter-setonitemclicklistener-problem

Answer (score 1):

the method onItemClick has the parameters

`AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id`

i'm not sure if your managedCursor is already moved to the correct position upon using it inside your onItemClick. you can try calling its `move` method first

```
c.moveToPosition(position)
```

Comment: "...i'm not sure if your managedCursor is already moved to the correct..." thats why normally we using `Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

Comment: Thanks for the Replies but I'm still getting the same error out put. The cursor seems to be moving to the correct row. If i click the first item in the list it shows row 0 the second row 1 and so on, my problem is the column. it is looking at column 2131034113 which is non-existent.