# Listview onitemclickevent crashes my app

Tags: android, listview

I am very new to Android development (though not to development in general). I am trying to create an app which:

Opens SMS inbox when a user taps a button and display them in listview (done)

```
Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

// Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
    new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
    R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When the user taps one message from the list, I want to get the body of the txt message (failed to do)

I am using this code in activity_main but it causes my app to close once I tap an item from the list

```
lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

    String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Logcat

```
16.828 32383-32383/com.example.taymour.moneywatch D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

02-17 20:42:16.828 32383-32383/com.example.taymour.moneywatch W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
02-17 20:42:16.828 32383-32383/com.example.taymour.moneywatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                                                    at com.example.taymour.moneywatch.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 20:42:17.473 32383-32389/com.example.taymour.moneywatch I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-17 20:42:17.684 32383-32389/com.example.taymour.moneywatch I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-17 20:42:21.158 32383-32383/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32383 SIG: 9

Comment: Please post you logcat too

Comment: How do I get the logcat, sorry am new

Answer (score 1):

```
        String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

to

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);

String item= textview.getText().toString();
```

oops: you have CursorAdapter. inside onItemClick.

```
  c.moveToPosition(position);

         String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
```

or

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
```

or try this [How to get the item id in an onItemClick handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553176/how-to-get-the-item-id-in-an-onitemclick-handler)

Comment: still crashes
`code` 
        lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);
        lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);

                String item= textView.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),item , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });